# Check if list is Flattened or not in Prolog

Tags: prolog

Given a list, I want to check whether the given list is flat or not using prolog.

```
Example:-

1. ?- is_flat([1,2,3]) should return true

2. ?- is_flat([1,f,2,r(p),8]) should return true

3. ?- is_flat([1,2,[3,e,w],u]) should return false
```

I am thinking of the logic i.e traverse each element of list and then using is_list check, whether the head is a list or not. I tried as:

```
is_flat([]).
is_flat([H|T]) :- is_list(H), is_flat(T).
```

But I don't think I am on the right track. Please suggest how I can solve this.

Comment: Why do you think that you are not on the right track? Did you test your code? (An alternative is to use [`maplist/2`](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=maplist/2)) and `is_list/2`.)

Comment: or `is_flat(L) :- forall(member(E,L),\+is_list(E)).`

Comment: Yes I have tested the code @DavidTonhofer It gives me wrong results. Basically we need to stop whenever we found that list contains a nested list and returns false. I also tried 
goal(H) :- is_list(H).
is_flat([]).
is_flat([H|T]) :- maplist(goal, H), is_flat(T).
It also give me wrong result.

Comment: Thanks @CapelliC that worked...

Comment: Should `is_flat([[a|b]]).` be true or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The approach as given is correct, we just need to "inverse the truth value" of the `is_list/2` test (or, more accurately, declare the proof as having failed as soon as we encounter a list). For good measure, I add a completely unnecessary message writing instruction:

```
is_flat([]).
is_flat([X|Xs]) :- 
   format("Examining ~q\n",[X]),
   \+ is_list(X),
   is_flat(Xs).
```

Then:

```
?- is_flat([a,b,c]).
Examining a
Examining b
Examining c
true.
```

But:

```
?- is_flat([a,[x,y,z],c]).
Examining a
Examining [x,y,z]
false.
```

**Using [maplist/2](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=maplist/2)**

This can be done compactly with `maplist/2`, which applies a predicate to each element and breaks off as soon as failure appears for such an application:

```
another_is_flat(List) :- maplist(not_is_list,List).

not_is_list(L) :- \+ is_list(L).
```

Then:

```
?- another_is_flat([a,b,c]).
true.

?- another_is_flat([a,[x,y,z],c]).
false.
```

**Using [forall/2](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=forall/2)**

Or using CapelliC's solution. `forall/2` is exactly made for this: It performs a test (in this case, `\+is_list(E)`) for every successful condition (in this case `member(E,L)`), and behaves like a short-circuiting AND (that also leaves no accidental bindings behind on success):

```
another_another_is_flat(L) :- forall(member(E,L),\+is_list(E)).
```

Then:

```
?- another_another_is_flat([a,b,c]).
true.

?- another_another_is_flat([a,[x,y,z],c]).
false.
```

Edge case:

```
?- another_another_is_flat([]) .
true.
```

The ["vacuous truth"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth): an empty list is correctly accepted.

Answer (score 1):

The short, non-rigorous way:

```
flat_list( [ []    | _  ] ) :- !, fail.       % not flat : a list containing the empty list
flat_list( [ [_|_] | _  ] ) :- !, fail.       % not flat : a list containing a non-empty list
flat_list( []             ) .                 %     flat : the empty list
flat_list( [ _     | Xs ] ) :- flat_list(Xs). %     flat : anything else, so long as the tail is flat
```